# What's the biblical basis to say that God is the only righteous being in the universe?

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-god, righteousness

I'm aware of several verses saying that God is righteous, but what's the biblical basis to say that God is or is not **the only righteous entity in the universe.**

Comment: Can you provide a quote from a Christ denomination/movement/published author who says this? I'd expect most Christians would say that angels are righteous.

Comment: @curiousdannii I've never heard of anyone saying an angel was righteous.

Comment: @Steve well they're not sinful, and they're morally capable, so what else would they be?

Comment: @curiousdannii I don't disagree with you -- I've just never heard anyone ever discuss this. Many angels did fall, so some are sinful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Humans

Paul quotes David in Romans 3:10-15.

> [Romans 3:10; NASB](https://ref.ly/Ro3.10;nasb) 
>  There is none righteous, not even one; 
>  There is none who understands, There is none who seeks for God; 
>  All have turned aside, together they have become useless; 
>  There is none who does good, There is not even one.

This sentiment is found in both [Psalm 14](https://ref.ly/ps14;nasb) and [Psalm 53](https://ref.ly/ps53;nasb).

The language here is speaking of humans. If your question is about non-human beings, then these statements probably don't apply.

Jesus responded to some praise given him, referring to him as “good teacher:”

> [Luke 18:19; NASB](https://ref.ly/lk18.19;nasb) 
>  Why do you call Me good? No one is good except God alone.

The same statement is recounted in [Mark 10:18](https://ref.ly/mk10.18;nasb).

Again, the context of this is probably about humans.

### Angels

I can't find a place where angels are actually referred to as being “righteous.” It *is* (or was at one time) possible for angels to sin.

> [2 Peter 2:4; NASB](https://ref.ly/2pe2.4;nasb) 
>  For if God did not spare angels when they sinned, but cast them into hell and bcommitted them to pits of darkness, reserved for judgment;

However, since we're not told very much about angels, particularly their creation, purpose, fallibility, and place in eternity, it's hard to say very much with certainty about them.